# grep or awk to match a line and the following with a specific pattern

Tags: awk, grep

I've started using a linux machine and I'm trying to do simple things...but very hard for me.
I need to select some specific lines that match with those reported in a second file.
Pratically I have a first file that is made like this:

```
>aba19  EN1 enl.or11    http://mar2043  annotation not avaliable
MASESEMGVVASJDHAGISFGVDDASDASDAFGDFGHWFACFQLIGIFLAYCLSRAITNN
QSDHKAJSDHKASJHKJAHKHKJSDGHYEIV
>clat38 EN2 enl.o   http://mar20s/Gene/Summary?5    annotation not avaliable
MNCEDCHILNAEAFKSKKDASDADICKSLKICGLVFGILALTLIVLFWGSKHFWPEVPKK
AYDMEHTFYSNGERGYCCASDSDDIYCSDRRGNRYCRRVCEPLLGYYPYPYCYQGGRVIC
RVIMPCDASDASDAOPWEIPQWFHNDJBVHAOISDOUIAODGNWWVARMLGRV
>coll9  EN4 ens4    http://mar2010.arch/Genary?g=E9 annotation not avaliable
MASKALDHLFKLJLÒFJASDJKLASDLAFJLFJFJLFJLAJFLKJFLAKFJFJLAFJLAL
ASDLASKDJASLKDJASLKJFALSKDJALKDJSKLDJLSDKJASLDKJSLDKSDLAKJKS
SILDUAISDALSDJALKDJASDLFATT 
>hihi9  EN9 ens44   http://mar2010.ariens/Geary?g=EN7   annotation not    avaliable
MGSLDLAÈPWOEMWBZMKSJDHAJKSDHAKSDHSDHSDHOASDAKSJDHKASJDHAAKHL
KTLSDKLHRFSDFHPHFGCJLJLJRKKFLDSFCGTVGEFAGGGDTHNNVCLSSVFVSEDG
HSDFSDWFKLGGMETVCSDFKVSQATPEFSSSDLFFDSRIQSIRDPASIPPEEMSPEFTT
LPECHGHARDAFSFGTLVESLLTILNEQVSADVLSSFQQTLHSTLLNPIPKCRPALCTLL
SDFLSDJFKLSDFLSKDFJM
```

And I have a second file with the list of patterns that I need to "extract" from the first file. The second file look like this:

```
>clat38
>coll9
```

Pratically I would like to have an output like this:

```
>clat38 EN2 enl.o   http://mar20s/Gene/Summary?5    annotation not avaliable
MNCEDCHILNAEAFKSKKDASDADICKSLKICGLVFGILALTLIVLFWGSKHFWPEVPKK
AYDMEHTFYSNGERGYCCASDSDDIYCSDRRGNRYCRRVCEPLLGYYPYPYCYQGGRVIC
RVIMPCDASDASDAOPWEIPQWFHNDJBVHAOISDOUIAODGNWWVARMLGRV
>coll9  EN4 ens4    http://mar2010.arch/Genary?g=E9 annotation not avaliable
MASKALDHLFKLJLÒFJASDJKLASDLAFJLFJFJLFJLAJFLKJFLAKFJFJLAFJLAL
ASDLASKDJASLKDJASLKJFALSKDJALKDJSKLDJLSDKJASLDKJSLDKSDLAKJKS
SILDUAISDALSDJALKDJASDLFATT
```

I tryed `grep -f file_2 file_1 > output` but I get only this:

```
>clat38
>coll9
```

May I add something more specific to grep?
Thank you for any advice!
Gab

Comment: Update your expected output because you can't get that output from your updated input file. Also - do you still just want to get the first line after your key value, or do you now need to get all the lines up the the next key value?

Comment: @EdMorton I need to get the first line and the rest lines up the next key value!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To search for a regular expression on a single line, use grep. Learn it from the man page and a couple of examples.

To substitute a string for a regular expression on a single line, use sed. Learn it from the man page and a couple of examples.

For all other text processing applications, use awk. Learn it from the book " Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition" By Arnold Robbins, http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/awkprog3/.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} $1 in a{c=2} c&&c--' file2 file1
```

If you want to print out more than 2 lines when you find the key you want, just change the value of c to 3 or 20 or whatever.

Given your comment below and your updated sample input, this should do what you want:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} /^>/{f=0} $1 in a{f=1} f' file2 file1
```

Comment: @EdMorton yes! it works!...thank you so much for all the help! You were very kind in assisting me and my problem!

Answer (score 1):

From the grep manpage:

```
-A NUM, --after-context=NUM
          Print NUM  lines  of  trailing  context  after  matching  lines.
          Places  a  line  containing  --  between  contiguous  groups  of
          matches.
```

So in this case just adding -A1 should work.

From the comments, a better solution would be:

`grep -xFA1 -f file_2 file_1 | grep -v "^\--"`

`-x` match whole lines

`-F` treat patterns as strings rather than regex

I had to add the second grep statement to remove the extra -- lines.

Comment: Try it with >clat3 in the file of keys and both >clat3 and >clat38 in the other file.

Comment: Good point. I guess you'd need to add `-x` to ensure whole line matches.

Comment: You'd also want to add -f to make sure you're doing a string comparison rather than an RE comparison and there might be some other flags you need to throw at it. It's not a horrible use of grep, though, you just have to think about it quite a bit to make sure you get all the options right or you end up with something that works on your sample input but then fails cryptically in later usage.

Comment: ...and now that the OP has updated his post, you'd need to remove the -x and do something else since now the key just appears at the START of the line in the data file.

Comment: The latest edit to the question breaks this solution since whole-line matches won't work any more. You can get round it by replacing -x with -w to match whole words instead but an awk solution is probably going to be easier to maintain. EDIT: Oh you just said that.

Comment: Yeah, and I feel like we may have a few more iterations of requirements still to come :-).

Comment: Just noticed the varying numbers of lines. Probably time to give up on grep. :)

Comment: Yeah, and that's the real problem with grep solutions - kinda like sed, just small changes in requirements mean complete re-writes or needing to switch to other tools. May as well just do it in awk in the first place!

Answer (score 0):

an awk one-liner should work for you:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}{x=$0;getline;if(x in a)print x"\n"$0}' file2 file1

kent$  head file1 file2
==> file1 <==
>aba19
 ALKSDJASDKASDLKASDL
>clat38
 PDASODJADASLDKALSKDLACASDLKAJ
>coll9
 AOSODADALSDKALDKASLDSAK
>hihi9
 JHASDASDJOASDJAOSD

==> file2 <==
>clat38
>coll9

kent$  awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}{x=$0;getline;if(x in a)print x"\n"$0}' file2 file1
>clat38
 PDASODJADASLDKALSKDLACASDLKAJ
>coll9
 AOSODADALSDKALDKASLDSAK
```

Comment: If you're considering using getline, make sure you've read http://awk.info/?tip/getline and fully understand all the caveats so you know what type of gun you're pointing at your foot :-).

Comment: @Kent I tryed it, but the ouput file is empty :(

Comment: @EdMorton thx for the info. did I use it wrong? can you point it out please? glad to know and learn. thank you in advance.

Comment: @Kent yes...anyway I don't get any result.. O_o

Comment: It's just not a case where getline is useful or appropriate. It results in a longer answer than not using getline, and you can't enhance it sensibly to print 10 lines (add 9 more getlines?) or to do other operations on the record it reads (since bypassing main body work loop). to be continued...

Comment: It also changes the values of some of the builtin variables so, for example, if you use NF after it to process the original record then you're no longer refering to the NF before it so you need to create tmp variables. You'd also run into problems if you were processing multiple files and testing for FNR==1 as it could jump right into line 2 of the 2nd file while bypassing your main work loop. et. etc. There's just WAY too much to consider to make it a good choice!

Comment: @EdMorton I'd like to know your opinion. and I don't mind if you could add that part in my answer (by editing my answer) to get better markdown format supports. thx.

Comment: @EdMorton yep, I knew that getline will set NF, $0... I was just too lazy to check the block beginning flag, since I saw the "block" is just one line.. you are absolutely right. getline could lead potential problems...

Comment: @Kent - not sure what you mean by "add that part in my answer", sorry.

Comment: @EdMorton i meant i am ok if you edit my answer to add your opinion/comments. forget it. ^_^

Comment: I edited the question adding a "real" piece of the first file...beacuse trying your codes on the test files they worked, but not trying them on the "real" files.

Comment: I just updated my answer. Basically you just need to change $0 to $1 in the awk solutions since you're matching on the first field of the line in the data file, not the whole line.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}{for(i in a)if(i==$0){print;getline;print}}' second_file first_file
```

Tested below:

```
> cat temp
>aba19
 ALKSDJASDKASDLKASDL
>clat38
 PDASODJADASLDKALSKDLACASDLKAJ
>coll9
 AOSODADALSDKALDKASLDSAK
>hihi9
 JHASDASDJOASDJAOSD

> cat temp2
>clat38
>coll9

> awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}{for(i in a)if(i==$0){print;getline;print}}' temp2 temp
>clat38
 PDASODJADASLDKALSKDLACASDLKAJ
>coll9
 AOSODADALSDKALDKASLDSAK
>
```

Comment: inefficient use of the array and see comments elsethread about getline.